# yocto - using gdb with externalsrc

Tags: gdb, yocto

We’re extending an existing Yocto project. We’d like to be able to selectively modify components of the project and build using the local modifications, then debug those modifications with gdb.

We’ve added these features to get gdb and the debug symbol packages into the image:
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks tools-debug"
IMAGE_FEATURES = "ssh-server-openssh dbg-pkgs"

We’ve added these variables to build from the local component code:
INHERIT += "externalsrc"
EXTERNALSRC_pn-[component] = “[local source code path]/[component]”

All seems well, as the build succeeds and the component in the image reflects local code changes. However, the component source code never makes it into the image, so it can’t be referenced in gdb.

Is there a secret to using dbg-pkgs and EXTERNALSRC together?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was due to a bug that was resolved in the 2.1 release, though I never pinpointed which commit actually resolved the issue. There's a [bugzilla entry covering the issue](https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8015) - if you are still experiencing this with 2.1 please do let me know.

Comment: Thank you for following up on this. I'm off this project, but will likely have to revisit this at some point, so I appreciate the information.